# Is it possible to record the open emails in Outlook 2010 with PowerShell so that they can be opened again later?

Tags: powershell, outlook

This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839516/outlook-2010-reopen-messages which was closed as not being a question.

I have a bad habit of keeping emails open in Outlook 2010 as a reminder of what needs to be done during the day since I am constantly interrupted.  What I would like to do is use PowerShell to get a list of the open emails so that if I need to close Outlook I know what I was working on before.

I am not worried about Outlook crashing, Outlook normally reopens all of the emails I had been working on automatically; the use case I am dealing with is when I have to manually close Outlook for a patch or to address some other issue.

What I would like to do is query the running Outlook process and see what messages are open; opening a new Outlook process via COM won't work since it would have a different list of open messages.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in PowerShell?  I can use another language if needed, but have been attempting to standardize on PowerShell where possible so that other people here can reuse any code I write.

One possibility I have considered is to launch Outlook via PowerShell so that I have a way to interact with the running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to get a reference to the running Outlook instance.

```
$outlook = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
```

Using the application object you then

- Iterate through the `outlook.Inspectors` collection
- Ask each individual `Inspector` for its `CurrentItem`
- Store whatever properties you need from this item (date? subject? entry id?)

Comment: Thank you for the reply; I tried this with Outlook and it didn't work.  However this gave me a direction to go in and after digging for a bit it appears that Outlook does not register with the Runtime Object Table (ROT).  As soon as I figure out how I'll mark this as the right answer since it works for applications that do register with ROT.

Comment: You learned wrong, I'm guessing you got mislead by some of the shadier google hits on the subject. Outlook registers with the ROT just fine, this approach is very common in win32 applications, and I just doublechecked in the powershell command line. If it doesn't work, provide more info. For instance, are you using a 64bits powershell on a 32bits Outlook?